# Why does initialisation outside of `viewDidLoad()` fail?

Tags: macos, swift

This doesn't compile:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let dir: NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Users/wilfred/")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    var folderContents: [NSURL]? = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(dir!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(), error: &error) as [NSURL]?
```

… but this does:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let dir: NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Users/wilfred/")

    var error: NSError? = nil

    var folderContents: [NSURL]? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.folderContents =  fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(dir!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(), error: &error) as [NSURL]?
    }
```

And notice that I only took the block for initialising `folderContents` from the declaration block and copied it over to the `viewDidLoad()` block. Why!?!?!

The error I'm getting is:

[image: compilation error]

… which seems bogus to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties are initialized before self is created, so when you want to get `fileManager` in `folderContents`, which is self.fileManager, self is not existing, so you can't get any property of self.
If you for example override the init method of any class, put a breakpoint in there and breakpoint to the properties, execute the code, you can see that the properties reached first, not the init.

Comment: Thanks. Just found another way in which Swift is different than Scala. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the docu it's stated that you need self in the first case:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
  let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
  let dir: NSURL? = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/Users/wilfred/")
  var error: NSError? = nil
  lazy var folderContents: [NSURL]? = self.fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(self.dir!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(), error: &self.error) as [NSURL]?
}
```