# Swift why my function call only works in the viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

A conceptual question. Why my function calls only work inside the viewDidLoad?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet var tableview2: UITableView!

    var forceView2 = [Float]()
    var stiffView2 = [Float]()
    var springNumView2 : NSInteger = NSInteger()  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        println(self.forceView2)
        println(self.stiffView2)
        println(self.springNumView2)

        var Answer = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2)

        println(Answer.self)            
    }
```

If   **var Answer = calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2)** is placed above the viewDidLoad, an error of 'ViewController2.type does not have a member named 'forceView2'.

Comment: Because you are calling a function in the body of a class. Not with a method.

Comment: Take a loook at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860704/why-does-initialisation-outside-of-viewdidload-fail/27865235#27865235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you move that line out of the method scope, you are actually turning a local variable into a property. This way the `Answer` property is visible to all instance methods, but also accessible from outside.

The problem in your case is that the property is initialized with the return value of an instance function, which indirectly references to `self` - but swift doesn't allow referencing to `self` during the initialization, that's the reason why you have a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a function in the class body and not within a method that's why.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course create a computed property. A property that returns a calculated value:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID259

Something along these lines should work:

```
var answer : [Float] { return calculate(forceView2, stiffView2, springNumView2) }
```

Comment: Gives an error Expected type... Var of Answer is array of float values.

Comment: @Cherry_thia, sorry it was missing the return value type after ":" and before "{". Can you try again with the edited version? Now it should be correct.