# Why is self allowed in the init() method, even though it fails a safety check?

Tags: swift

> **Safety Check #4**
>
> An initializer cannot call any instance methods, read the values of any instance properties, or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of initialization is complete.

```
class Fruit {
  var name: String
  init(fruitName: String) {
    // in phase one
    self.name = fruitName; // using self during the property assignment
    // phase one is complete
  }
}

let orange = Fruit(fruitName: "Orange");
```

So, how does this get special dispensation to use self, and to know what self refers to?

Comment: Either I misinterpret your question, or you misinterpreted that quote. Does that code work? Also, maybe [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431011/swift-why-i-cant-call-method-from-override-init) is useful to you.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes that code works in Playground. I understand the quote to mean that when `self.name = fruitName` is evaluated, `self` shouldn't exist until `name` has been assigned, therefore it would fail.

Comment: You are simply setting an initial value for a stored property. That does not count as "refer to self as a value".

Answer (score 0):

> or refer to self as a value until after the first phase of
>   initialization is complete.

This is a case here the first phase is ready, how you want assign properties of your instance without self ? A more useful example is when you override init method.

You can't use self before super.init()

Comment: How is the first phase ready, the point at which I assign `self.name = fruitName`, the property has not been assigned, therefore Phase 1 hasn't finished.

Comment: It's not what they mean with first phase of initialization, like I said with my example

Answer (score 0):

In two-phase initialization, phase 1 ends when *top of the chain is reached, and the final class in the chain has ensured that all of its stored properties have a value*.

This means:

`class Fruit {
    var name: String
    init(fruitName: String) {
        self.someFunction() // compilation error, since not all stored properties have value yet, self is not allowed to refer as a value
        self.name = fruitName; // self is refer here only for initializing property 
        // phase one completed
        self.someFunction() // no problem here
    }
    func someFunction() {
        print("phase one completed")
    }
}`

Comment: This is not correct. Try `let otherFruit = self` *before* assigning an initial value to `self.name`, it will give a compiler error because phase 1 is not yet completed.